# Error says that it can't transform string into int

Tags: c#, string, int, switch-statement, console.readline

```
      string num;
            num = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            switch (num)
            {case 1:
            Console.WriteLine(one);
```

I'm trying to do a c# project where you type a number from 1 to 100 and you see the wrote version of it.

Comment: The error is telling you the truth. Strings need to be parsed into Numeric values. int.Parse() is the droid you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `num` is a string.  But you're trying to compare it with an integer here:

```
case 1:
```

The quickest solution would be to compare it with a string:

```
case "1":
```

Alternatively, and possibly as a learning experience for you, you may want to try converting `num` to an `int`.  Take a look at `int.TryParse` for that.  An example might look like this:

```
string num = Console.ReadLine();
int numValue = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(num, out numValue)) {
    // The value entered was not an integer.  Perhaps show the user an error message?
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned only wanting to print numbers between 1 and 100.
This version does that.

```
var consoleResponse = Console.ReadLine();

if (int.TryParse(consoleResponse, out int parsedValue) 
        && parsedValue >= 1 
        && parsedValue <= 100) {
    Console.WriteLine(parsedValue);
}
```